# Android prevent indexing of files on a sd card

Tags: android, indexing, maps

Is there a way to prevent android os from indexing files on a sd card? We have an application that uses offline map tiles and even for just one city its about 3 million files.

Every time we reboot the device or insert an sd card the android.process.media process runs for about 2 hours trying to index everything on the sd card. Which also for some reason causes the media storage app to fill up all the hard disk space on the device.

We've tried using a .nomedia file in our map tiles folder but it does not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a total hack but what works for us is moving whatever you don't want indexed into the Android/data folder on the sd card.